# How to keep the array structure as it is, when returning as JSON?

Tags: php, json, api, decode, encode

I have a problem, I have a multidimensional array of some data that I am returning as JSON through an API, I want the data as a JSON array, the array is structured properly in PHP but when I return it through API as JSON it becomes a JSON object of objects, I want the data in same structure as I kept in PHP while producing the array. I have tried casting the object as array, array is perfect in PHP but IN JSON it becomes object of objects. How could i return JSON data as array.

```
{
   "standards":{
      "standard_1":{
         "subjects":{
            "English":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Physics":{
               "topics":{
                  "topic":[
                     {
                        "id":"2",
                        "standard_id":"1",
                        "subject_id":"3",
                        "topic":"topic",
                        "title":"dgfdgfdg",
                        "option_1":"dfgdfggdgfdg",
                        "option_2":"dfgfd",
                        "option_3":"gdfgfdg",
                        "option_4":"dfgdfgdg",
                        "correct_answer":"option_2"
                     }
                  ],
                  "test topic":[
                     {
                        "id":"6",
                        "standard_id":"1",
                        "subject_id":"3",
                        "topic":"test topic",
                        "title":"title",
                        "option_1":"1",
                        "option_2":"2",
                        "option_3":"3",
                        "option_4":"4",
                        "correct_answer":"option_2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            "sports":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Maths":{
               "topics":{
                  "topic":[
                     {
                        "id":"1",
                        "standard_id":"1",
                        "subject_id":"21",
                        "topic":"topic",
                        "title":"This is a updated test question",
                        "option_1":"1",
                        "option_2":"2",
                        "option_3":"3",
                        "option_4":"4",
                        "correct_answer":"option_2"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            "test subject":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_2":{
         "subjects":{
            "Math":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Chemistry":{
               "topics":{
                  "topic":[
                     {
                        "id":"4",
                        "standard_id":"2",
                        "subject_id":"4",
                        "topic":"topic",
                        "title":"sfsfsfs",
                        "option_1":"fdsfs",
                        "option_2":"fsfs",
                        "option_3":"fsdfsdf",
                        "option_4":"sdfdsfds",
                        "correct_answer":"option_1"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            "test sub":{
               "topics":{
                  "fghgfh":[
                     {
                        "id":"3",
                        "standard_id":"2",
                        "subject_id":"19",
                        "topic":"fghgfh",
                        "title":"Title",
                        "option_1":"fhfhf",
                        "option_2":"hfhf",
                        "option_3":"hgfhf",
                        "option_4":"fhfghfhfh",
                        "correct_answer":"option_4"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_3":{
         "subjects":{
            "Sports":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_4":{
         "subjects":{
            "new subject":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Computer":{
               "topics":{
                  "Basics":[
                     {
                        "id":"7",
                        "standard_id":"4",
                        "subject_id":"24",
                        "topic":"Basics",
                        "title":"What is a computer",
                        "option_1":"Machine",
                        "option_2":"Aeroplane",
                        "option_3":"Device",
                        "option_4":"Robot",
                        "correct_answer":"option_1"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_5":{
         "subjects":{
            "Math":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "History":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_6":{
         "subjects":[

         ]
      },
      "standard_7":{
         "subjects":{
            "Sports":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Civics":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_8":{
         "subjects":[

         ]
      },
      "standard_9":{
         "subjects":[

         ]
      },
      "standard_10":{
         "subjects":{
            "History":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            },
            "Math":{
               "topics":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "standard_11":{
         "subjects":[

         ]
      },
      "standard_12":{
         "subjects":[

         ]
      }
   }
}

[standard_1] => Array
            (
                [subjects] => Array
                    (
                        [English] => Array
                            (
                                [topics] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [Physics] => Array
                            (
                                [topics] => Array
                                    (
                                        [topic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 2
                                                        [standard_id] => 1
                                                        [subject_id] => 3
                                                        [topic] => topic
                                                        [title] => dgfdgfdg
                                                        [option_1] => dfgdfggdgfdg
                                                        [option_2] => dfgfd
                                                        [option_3] => gdfgfdg
                                                        [option_4] => dfgdfgdg
                                                        [correct_answer] => option_2
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [test topic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 6
                                                        [standard_id] => 1
                                                        [subject_id] => 3
                                                        [topic] => test topic
                                                        [title] => title
                                                        [option_1] => 1
                                                        [option_2] => 2
                                                        [option_3] => 3
                                                        [option_4] => 4
                                                        [correct_answer] => option_2
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [sports] => Array
                            (
                                [topics] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [Maths] => Array
                            (
                                [topics] => Array
                                    (
                                        [topic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 1
                                                        [standard_id] => 1
                                                        [subject_id] => 21
                                                        [topic] => topic
                                                        [title] => This is a updated test question
                                                        [option_1] => 1
                                                        [option_2] => 2
                                                        [option_3] => 3
                                                        [option_4] => 4
                                                        [correct_answer] => option_2
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [test subject] => Array
                            (
                                [topics] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Any idea?

Comment: can we have array structure ?

Comment: Sure, i have updated the question.

Comment: If you don't like `{}` in JSON and want it to be `[]` format, then you need to keep PHP array as collection of values without keys(except numeric keys which PHP manages internally). JSON you are getting is in correct format and clients going to use this will have no problem on their PHP backend when they use `json_decode($API_DATA,true);`

Comment: As @vivek_23 mentions about keys, for your example data, you have to strip out `standards` (the first object key), and then remove all keynames of `standard_1` `standard_*n*` etc. So that each value is in an array `[0] [1] etc`. If you want to keep the `standard_*n*` etc... then what you are asking for is impossible. You either have an enumerated array of values, or you have a list of keynames and their values.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably `json_decode($jsonString,true);` . It will convert the objects inside the json into arrays

Comment: Thanks, But i m not going to parse the JSON object in PHP again.

Comment: so the real problem is not decoding json into arrays but actually forcing json_encode to convert objects into arrays? I think you need to clarify your question a little.

Comment: yes u got it, i want the JSON to be an array instead object of objects.

Comment: then there's no solution to this. JSON, by design has lists (no keys) and objects (which supports keys). You can see that your json contains keys (the first one being "standards") and that makes the json converter make it an object as a result.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your json object to be returned as array in php just use `json_decode($json,true);` [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

if you want to be sure that your php array is correctly converted to json use `json_encode($phpArray,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` [more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: That's not the case, u can refer to above comments to get a clear picture of my question, thanks :)

Comment: as janmy said in there . it is because of your php array that passed to `json_encode` function . so if you want you can change your php array. if not able, use that as it generate. :-)